Using T-SQL to get a running total in columns
I am trying to write a T-SQL query to get the running total quantity of columns, basically after everything I have a temp table that has the data I need
SELECT 
    MQ.[Company], 
    MQ.[status],
    MQ.[Facility],
    MQ.[ItemCode],
    MQ.[Style],
    MQ.[Description],
    CONVERT(date, MQ.[PlannedDate], 101) AS [PlannedDate],
    MONTH(CONVERT(date, CONVERT(date, MQ.[PlannedDate], 101))) AS [PlannedDateMonth],
    YEAR(CONVERT(date, CONVERT(date, MQ.[PlannedDate], 101))) AS [PlannedDateYear],
    MQ.[On-HandApprove],
    MQ.[TransactionQuantity],
    MQ.[OrderNumber],
    MQ.[OrderLineNumber],
    MQ.[WorkOrderNumber],
    MQ.[PurchaseOrderNumber],
    MQ.[PurchaseOrderLineNumber],
    MQ.[OrderQuantity],
    MQ.[InTransit],
    MQ.[OutstandingQuantity],
    MQ.[PODueDate]
FROM 
    #MainQuery MQ
ORDER BY 
    MQ.[ItemCode], CONVERT(date, MQ.[PlannedDate], 101)

However I am trying to get a "running total quantity" based on the item code, and which facility it is located at. Created some fake data as



Facility
ItemCode
PlannedDate
On-HandApprove
TransactionQuantity
OutstandingQuantity
Running Total Quantity




P00
07J000061COY050
2/23/2024
1189
984
984
1189


P00
07J000061COY050
5/10/2024
1189
-192
0
1381


P00
07J000061COY050
5/10/2024
1189
192
0
997


P00
07J000061COY050
5/10/2024
1189
312
312
997


P00
07J000061COY050
6/14/2024
1189
-24
0
1021


P00
07J000061COY050
6/14/2024
1189
24
0
997


P00
07J000061COY051
2/23/2024
1500
500
984
1984


P00
07J000061COY051
5/10/2024
1500
-192
0
2176


P00
07J000061COY051
5/10/2024
1500
192
0
1984


D00
07J000061COY051
5/10/2024
1500
312
312
1500



The formula to get it would be
For the first record per Itemcode/Facility:
(On-HandApprove - TransactionQuantity + OutstandingQuantity) = Running Total Quantity
For the next records per Itemcode/Facility:
(Previous Running Total Quantity - TransactionQuantity + OutstandingQuantity) = Running Total Quantity
So this is basically what I'm after, I have tried this
(SUM(MQ.[TransactionQuantity]) OVER (PARTITION BY MQ.[ItemCode],MQ.[Facility] ORDER BY CONVERT(date, MQ.[PlannedDate], 101) ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) - ISNULL(MQ.[On-HandApprove], 0) ) + ISNULL(MQ.[OutstandingQuantity], 0) AS [RunningTotalTransactionQuantity]

and a few different alterations of it but cant seem to get it the way I need it.....please help!!

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.v

As a seperate note, a DISTINCT with that many columns has a "smell" to it. As you don't have a GROUP BY or a JOIN, sounds like you have data issues you need to address.

IN  (@Facility)  probably won't do what you are hoping too

Removed some of the confusing, the temp table handled all the joins and such i was basically just needing assistance with the last part, so removed distinct for ya! And IN (@facility) Was just so i could pass certain parameters to it to test it out, easier to look at a few and not a bunch

@ThomA Thank you, i was unaware of that :)

min([On-HandApprove]) over (partition by Facility, ItemCode) + sum(OutstandingQuantity - TransactionQuantity) over (partition by Facility, ItemCode order by PlannedDate) You may need to create distinct rows before this calculation though.

A note on shawnt00's answer above. If you are new new window functions the nuances of the expression may not be obvious. When over() omits both order by and range/rows, the window frame is all rows in the partition. The min() function picks a single value from that set. When over() contains an order by but omits range/rows, the window frame defaults to RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW.  The sum() function then yields a running total.  See SELECT - OVER Clause (Transact-SQL).

I created a fiddle from the example data and included Shawnt00's column. I hope this helps us verify a solution. https://dbfiddle.uk/GpsleA08

With ties in the date you may need: min([OnHandApprove]) over (partition by Facility, ItemCode) + sum(OutstandingQuantity - TransactionQuantity) over (partition by Facility, ItemCode order by PlannedDate, TransactionQuantity rows between unbounded preceding and current row)

@SamuelDague - For the first three rows - if you start with 1189, add 192, and then subtract 192, how do you get an expected running total of 997?

Okay i finally got it, and i believe i had it before in one of my other variations i tried. However what i endede up with (And i'm sure there is a better, more efficient way BUT this is working)
SELECT 
    MQ.[Company], 
    MQ.[status],
    MQ.[Facility],
    MQ.[ItemCode],
    MQ.[Style],
    MQ.[Description],
    CONVERT(date, MQ.[PlannedDate], 101) AS [PlannedDate],
    MONTH(CONVERT(date, CONVERT(date, MQ.[PlannedDate], 101))) AS [PlannedDateMonth],
    YEAR(CONVERT(date, CONVERT(date, MQ.[PlannedDate], 101))) AS [PlannedDateYear],
    MQ.[On-HandApprove],
    MQ.[TransactionQuantity],
    MQ.[OrderNumber],
    MQ.[OrderLineNumber],
    MQ.[WorkOrderNumber],
    MQ.[PurchaseOrderNumber],
    MQ.[PurchaseOrderLineNumber],
    MQ.[OrderQuantity],
    MQ.[InTransit],
    MQ.[OutstandingQuantity],
    MQ.[PODueDate]
,SUM(MQ.[TransactionQuantity] + ISNULL(MQ.[InTransit], 0) + MQ.[OutstandingQuantity]) OVER (
    PARTITION BY MQ.[ItemCode], MQ.[Facility]
    ORDER BY CONVERT(date, MQ.[PlannedDate], 101), MQ.[status],MQ.[ItemCode]
    ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
) + MQ.[On-HandApprove] AS [RunningTotalTransactionQuantity]
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY MQ.ItemCode, MQ.Facility ORDER BY CONVERT(date, MQ.PlannedDate, 101)) AS RowNumber
INTO #FinalTable
FROM 
    #MainQuery MQ
ORDER BY 
    MQ.[ItemCode], CONVERT(date, MQ.[PlannedDate], 101)

    
SELECT * FROM 
#FinalTable
ORDER BY [ItemCode], RowNumber 

So to get the correct calculations i set it up like this
SUM(MQ.[TransactionQuantity] + ISNULL(MQ.[InTransit], 0) + MQ.[OutstandingQuantity]) OVER (
    PARTITION BY MQ.[ItemCode], MQ.[Facility]
    ORDER BY CONVERT(date, MQ.[PlannedDate], 101), MQ.[status],MQ.[ItemCode]
    ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
) + MQ.[On-HandApprove] AS [RunningTotalTransactionQuantity]

However the problem was the results wasnt adding up when however i believe it was because of the [PlannedDate] column, the date field would look like '2024-05-10'. Ordering by PlannedDate is what i needed to do but the values were the same so i think it would just put it in a random order each time making it look like the values were off but they were just out of order. So i added a ROW_NUMBER column as well
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Y.ItemCode, Y.Facility ORDER BY CONVERT(date, Y.PlannedDate, 101)) AS RowNumber

This way, i can just order it by RowNumber, making sure that each row is in the same exact spot as when the calculation took place. So now the data matches up! Thanks everyone for your help/input!



PlannedDate
PlannedDateMonth
PlannedDateYear
On-HandApprove
TransactionQuantity
OrderQuantity
InTransit
OutstandingQuantity
RunningTotalTransactionQuantity




2024-02-23
2
2024
1496.000000
984.000000
984.000000
0.000000
984.000000
3464.000000


2024-05-10
5
2024
1496.000000
-312.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
3152.000000


2024-05-10
5
2024
1496.000000
-192.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
2960.000000


2024-05-10
5
2024
1496.000000
192.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
3152.000000


2024-05-10
5
2024
1496.000000
312.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
3464.000000


2024-06-14
6
2024
1496.000000
-24.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
3440.000000


2024-06-14
6
2024
1496.000000
24.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
3464.000000




SUM() OVER is generally the best technique for this available today, so if you're doing that you're at least likely close. But if you have multiple records per day you may want to add existing fields to get a determinist sort order, rather than an additional row_number() projection.
